# How to show featured products from a certain category only?

Tags: magento-1.8, category, featured-product

How can I show featured products from a certain category only?

I managed to create 'featured product' as one of the attributes for my products and I have 'tagged' a few products to this attribute. But my problem is I only want to show the featured product from one particular category only.

I have 'wine', 'food', 'gifts', etc as my categories. And each category has their own featured products, so when I am on wine category view page, I want to show the featured ones from wine category only, and then I want to show the ones from food category only when I am on food category view page.

I followed the guides here to create 'featured product' attribute,

1.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/how_to_create_a_featured_product

2.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/84852/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12288000/158325

---

Found a working solution using Alan Storm's advice.

**/template/custom/featured-product.phtml**

```
<?php
$_categoryId = $this->getCategoryId();

$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryId)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
    ->setOrder('price', 'ASC');
?>

<div class="featured-product">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__( $this->getLabel() ); ?></h2>

    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <div class="item">
            <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
            </a>

            <a class="product-name" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a>

            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
        </div>

        <?php
        // Note: Exit after first product.
        break;
        ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

In short, the collection is manually generated rather than receiving a collection (as my initial attempt did):

```
<?php $_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection() ?>
<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->getSize(); ?>
```

## Using in a CMS Page:

```
{{block type="core/template" category_id="13" label="Product of the Month" template="custom/featured-product.phtml" }}
```

## Using in a template:

**/layout/local.xml**

```
<default>
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="core/template" name="custom.featuredProduct" as="featured_product" template="custom/featured-product.phtml">
            <action method="setData"><key>category_id</key><value>13</value></action>
            <action method="setData"><key>label</key><value>Product of the Month</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

**/template/page/html/footer.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('featured_product') ?>
```

## Helpful resources:

How to get a product collection:

- http://overlycaffeinated.com/2011/02/get-all-sale-products-from-a-category-in-magento/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272818/magento-products-by-categories

Using magic getters/setters:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4008251/1497746
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4006374/1497746